# Can you identify this plant, please?

Tags: identification, shrubs

[image][image]

This shrub first appeared in my overflow garden two summers ago.  As I was missing my Snow Day Surprise plant, I off-handedly assumed it was that.  It has reappeared in the same spot two more consecutive years ~ bigger, but with no other off shoots ~ which makes me think it is not a weed.

It is about 4 feet tall (I tried adding a pic of the whole bush but I had gone over the accepted Mb limit) with thick green stalks coming out of the insignificant root; off of which there are many smaller green branches. There are lance shaped leaves (3 inches in length) on the branches.  The pure white flowers are profuse and have been in bloom for about a month now.  They close up in the heat of the day and open when the air is cooler.  There are five heart shaped petals (1 inch in diameter) and a bulbous pod immediately beneath the flower.

I would have thought with that many descriptors I could have easily found it on google; but to no avail.  Thank you kindly for your insight; I'd like to figure out what to do with it!

Sincerely, Karen
Oh, I am in Zone 5 Nova Scotia

Comment: Please can you try to re-attach a photo of the whole bush?  The reason I ask is because Silene latifolia has a USDA hardiness rating of 5 - 9 which 
puts your location is at the colder end. As it is normally a biennial or short lived perennial it is unlikely S. latifolia would have grown as big as a 4 foot shrub. ( with presumably 'woody' branches ). So perhaps it's a false I.D.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like White Campion to me, Latin name Silene latifolia, a biennial or perennial plant, but check the image here http://www.toronto-wildlife.com/Plants/Pink_Carnation_family/plants_family_pink_carnation.html

In order to compare leaves, you should  google 'Silene latifolia foliage' to check it's the right plant.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Bamboo.  I think this is white campion 'silene latifolia', or bladder campion is what I've always known it as.  I've dealt with bladder campion a lot which can get very weedy if you allow it to go to seed.

Comment: Thank you Bamboo and Tyler K.  I checked out the link you sent and a few other sites for White Campion.  The link you gave, shows a distinct difference b/w white and Bladder Campion; with the bladder having long tentacles that mine doesn't have.  My flower is identical to the White Campion!!  That said, most information gives the plant to be around 2 foot in height, 3 feet maximum.  I just stood beside mine ~ I am 5'4" and it is up to my eyes.  Maybe it just likes the 100% composted cow manure in my overflow garden. Thank you kindly for helping me!  I've no idea where it came from. 

Comment: Bladder campion is the common name for Silene vulgaris - the petals are formed differently to those on Silene latifolia (white campion), as you've discovered, Karen. Yet another demonstration of how inaccurate common  names can be, Tyler K!